# Changing the default behavior of tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to change the default behaviors of various widgets. 
In particular I want to set the default relief of labels to SUNKEN, the default background to grey, the default foreground to blue, etc....

I have tried add_option, but the only thing that took was "*font","arial 32".

I wish to do this as I have one screen that has many labels on it and the code gets messy with the same relief=SUNKEN line after line.

Thanks

```
    self.PartInputFrame=Frame(self.parent,width=self.parent.winfo_screenwidth(),height=self.parent.winfo_screenheight())
    self.PartInputFrame.pack_propagate(0)
    self.PartInputFrame.config(background='blue')

    self.PartInputLabel=Label(self.PartInputFrame,anchor=CENTER)
    self.PartInputLabel.config(fg='white',bg='blue')
    self.PartInputLabel.config(text='Part Program Input Information')
    self.PartInputLabel.place(rely=.1,relx=.5,anchor=CENTER)
    self.PartInputLabel.config(font=("arial",32))


    self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Font","arial 32")
    self.PartInputFrame.option_add("foreground","white")
    self.PartInputFrame.option_add("background","blue")
    self.PartInputFrame.option_add("relief","SUNKEN")



    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text="Polyline").place(rely=.3,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='"X" Origin Set').place(rely=.35,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Pattern(s) Long').place(rely=.4,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Pattern(s) Wide').place(rely=.45,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Repeat Length').place(rely=.5,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Repeat Width').place(rely=.55,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Mirror (Y or N)').place(rely=.6,relx=.1)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Pattern Type').place(rely=.65,relx=.1)


    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Part Program').place(rely=.3,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Part Drawing Number').place(rely=.35,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Plates Produced').place(rely=.40,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Plates Remaining').place(rely=.45,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Left Setup').place(rely=.50,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Right Setup').place(rely=.55,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Plate Lenght').place(rely=.60,relx=.5)
    Label(self.PartInputFrame,text='Plate Width').place(rely=.65,relx=.5)
```

Comment: `option_add` is the proper way to change the default attributes of tkinter widgets. If that didn't work for you, you likely did something wrong. Without seeing what you did it will be difficult to for us to help.

Comment: Here is a bit of the code that is not working. The font is changing but nothing else is.

Comment: You don't need to show all those labels in your example, one or two is sufficient, and make your code easier to nderstand.

Comment: If I did not include them someone else would ask why I want to do what I want to do for just 2 or three labels. :-)

Comment: Unrelated to the question asked, you should seriously consider learning how to use `pack` or `grid`. Using place makes your GUI hard to maintain, and it will have problems adapting to different screen sizes or resolutions, and different font sizes. `place` really isn't good as a general purpose layout tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered my own question. As usual it is a matter of figuring out what to search for.

```
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Font","arial 32")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("foreground","white")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("background","blue")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("relief","SUNKEN")
```

option_add is looking for a path to the option. Not the option itself. Where I set the Font, I placed a wildcard in front of it (looked right at it but never saw it). Effectively changing the Font for everything.

Where I set the 'foreground' I did not create a path.

The correct code:

```
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Font","arial 32")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*foreground","white")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*background","blue")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*relief","SUNKEN")
```

This will change foreground,background, etc, globally.

The (more) correct code:

```
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Label.Font","arial 32")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Label.foreground","white")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Label.background","blue")
self.PartInputFrame.option_add("*Label.relief","SUNKEN")
```

will change defaults for Labels (globally)
( still do not quite understand the path before *Label. When I figure that out I will amend this answer)