# Tkinter themes and backgrounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In tkinter you can choose a background for text widget, or background for toplevel widget(children windows)....etc, but is there any way to set a whole background for the whole gui application(set a background for all widgets at once with same color), instead of picking each background for each widget?

Comment: I think you are looking for `option_add`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832457/13629335

Comment: @Atlas435 before i submit this question as "already answered", i still dont understand how option_add work, because when i do it, the background for text widget for example doesnt change.

Comment: You could use `ttk` which is themed, but dont go for customizing it, its tiresome, use the default skins, its fun

Comment: @ghazigamer You need to put the `option_add` lines before creating the widgets, they don't apply to already existing widgets.

Comment: @CoolCloud ttk also work the same (i have to set a background for each widget) unless i am mistaken?

Comment: @ghazigamer You can change the background of all ttk widgets with `style.configure('.', background='black')`